# AutoIt Wait until browser window is visible not working as expected

Tags: windows, autoit, windows-scripting

Consider that I have the handle (`$browser_handle`) of a web browser window ('firefox') available in my AutoIt script.

I would like perform some keystrokes after I know that the firefox browser window is open and visible on my display so that I can bring it to focus using -

```
WinActivate($browser_handle)
```

or

```
WinWaitActive($browser_handle)
```

To make sure that the window is visible before I try to bring it into focus I have a `while` loop which waits till the state of the window handle is visible (2).

```
While (Not BitAND(WinGetState($browser_handle), 2)) WEnd //until window visible
```

If I use a `Sleep(5000)` function before the while loop then I do not face any issues.

If I do not use an arbitrary `Sleep` function in my script, the `While`loop condition never becomes `true` and turns into an infinite loop.

When I tried to check what the return value of `WinGetState($browser_handle)` is when there is no `Sleep` function,

It remains **5** even if the browser is visible and becomes **0** after the browser window is closed.

I'm unable to understand why the `WinGetState`return value never becomes **2**(visible) even if the browser is visible when there is no `Sleep` function.

This is a test code which can reproduce the issue -

```
#include <Constants.au3>
Local $browser_name = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet   Explorer\iexplore.exe'
Run($browser_name)

ProcessWait('iexplore.exe')

Local $browsers = ProcessList('iexplore.exe')

Local $pid = $browsers[1][1];

_WinActiveByPID($pid)

Local $sText = WinGetTitle("[ACTIVE]")

; Display the window title.
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", $sText)

Func _WinActiveByPID($pid)   ;False to WinActivate, True to just see if it's active
Local $aWL = WinList()
For $iCC = 1 To $aWL[0][0]
        If ($aWL[$iCC][0] <> '') And _
            (WinGetProcess($aWL[$iCC][1]) = $pid) Then
                 While (Not BitAND(WinGetState($aWL[$iCC][1]), 2))
                    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", WinGetState($aWL[$iCC][1]))
                 WEnd
                 WinWait($aWL[$iCC][1])
                 WinActivate($aWL[$iCC][1])
                 WinWaitActive($aWL[$iCC][1])
                 Return 1
        EndIf
 Next
Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
EndFunc
```

Note:

1. [WinWait](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) does not work in this situation, If you see the example in the link there is a `Sleep` after `WinWait`, this function returns even if the window is hidden.
2. The browser window in my original script is not launched using `Run`, it is a Java program which opens the browser. I know that the `Run` method returns the PID of the browser which I can use to resolve this issue but since it starts from Java I have to use `ProcessList` to obtain the PID of the browser.

Please let me know how I can get this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got thing too complicated for no reason there. Let me show you.

```
Local $browser_name = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
Run($browser_name)

ProcessWait('iexplore.exe')
Sleep(500)      ; because ProcessWait will exit when the process is created not when the window is visible. If your computer is slow you will have an problem

Local $BrowsersHWND = WinList()
Local $hBrowserHandle[2]

For $i = 0 To $BrowsersHWND[0][0] -1
    If StringInStr($BrowsersHWND[$i][0], "Internet Explorer") Then
        $hBrowserHandle[0] = $BrowsersHWND[$i][0]   ;title
        $hBrowserHandle[1] = $BrowsersHWND[$i][1]   ;handle
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next

If $hBrowserHandle[0] = "" Or $hBrowserHandle[1] = "" Then Exit MsgBox(0, 0, "Internet Explorer not found")

Local $hState = WinGetState($hBrowserHandle[0])
Local $sVisibleStates[24] = [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]  ;visible states
Local $hCheck = False
For $j = 0 To UBound($sVisibleStates) -1
    If $hState = $sVisibleStates[$j] Then
        ConsoleWrite("Window state(visisble): " & $hState & @LF)
        $hCheck = True
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next

If $hCheck = False Then
    ConsoleWrite("Activating: " & $hBrowserHandle[0] & @LF)
    WinActivate($hBrowserHandle[0])
EndIf
```

I have added all the cases of states where your window would be visible.
`WinWait` will not activate any window and I recommend you never use it. It could freeze a script for ever without reason. I will not explain why because it would take pages but avoid it. Also avoid using `WinWaitActive`. For similar reasons.
You have too many issues in your code that's why I completely changed it. Not worth explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not necessarily with the code, but possibly with the logic.  I could be way off base here, but maybe we should not be looking for a state of 2, but something closer to 15.

A sample with notepad:

```
$WIN_STATE_EXISTS (1) = Window exists
$WIN_STATE_VISIBLE (2) = Window is visible
$WIN_STATE_ENABLED (4) = Window is enabled
$WIN_STATE_ACTIVE (8) = Window is active
```

A window that is active (8), enabled (4), visible(2), and exists(1) will have a windows state of 15.

```
; Look for notepad and display WindowState number
if WinExists("[Class:Notepad]") Then
   MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Found")

   WinActivate("[Class:Notepad]")
   $WinState = WinGetState("[Class:Notepad]")
   MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", $WinState)
EndIf
```